# How to drive a relay from a MOSFET/IRF?

Tags: mosfet, relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5153J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello,

I would drive a machine to pilot its ON/OFF status.
So in idea it should be OK but is it?
What requires attention or this is an error in concept?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That (IRF9530) is a **P channel** mosfet.  But you have an **N channel** mosfet symbol.
The circuit is correct for an N FET, but not for a P FET.
When you select an N FET to be driven by a digital circuit, you need to make sure that the Vgs-th is low enough that the 3.3V or 5V circuit can drive it.  There are a class of FETs that are designed for digital control.  I would look into one of those.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine to me, the freewheel diode is the most important part.  7.4V will give good saturation for the FET.  The only concern is whether it’s an ideal voltage for the relay coil, 6 and 12V are common but perhaps you’ve found a 7V one somewhere.